# How do I get GETCH() like behaviour in C++ that is time based?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So I made a little game (console app) and at the end I wanna display an end game screen. If the player dies while trying to move somewhere they'll be in the middle of pressing a key. My solution that uses _getch() to halt the console will catch that key and instantly close the console without giving the player a chance to see what happened. It makes it look like the game crashed.

I need something time based, that doesn't react to any keys for a few seconds, but then does.

```
int main()
{
    //game loop is here somewhere, exits when player is dead
    if (player.isDead())
        {
            displayGameOverScreen();
            return 0;
        }   
}

void displayGameOverScreen()
{
    std::cout << "You died.";
    _getch();//if player is still pressing keys
             //console instantly closes
}
```

Comment: Sure! I edited my post to show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are working under Windows, so you can put Sleep(2000) for 2 seconds of sleep or better solution if you close the window when user press directly a button that reserved for, like 'Q' letter and 'R' is could be for retry / restart in this case, let the game re-initialise itself and remove return statement after displayGameOverScreen().

Problem with Sleep when the users press a key while in its sleeping, the key press will have effect immediately after sleep have done.

Comment: Modern C++ cross-platform solution would be [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for), e.g. `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I used in the end.

Comment: @dewaffled: "std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));"

Problem with modern C++ is complexity by invoking objects with another object with a constructor, therefore performance impact presents and larger stack as results. Of 'Corse the problem only reasonable on heavy tasks or cyclic events. I think just worth to mention sometimes a simply #ifdef WIN32 ... more enough and telling this meanwhile Im using both.

Answer (score 1):

After `displayGameOverScreen();`

add `system("pause");`

and the screen should be frozen on the spot and will not close.

If that doesn't work, add `Sleep(4000);` instead of `system("pause");`
and it will stay for 4 seconds before closing.

Keep in mind that you should add `#include<Windows.h>`